# Naming getter method with 'get_' when attribute is already present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, naming

I'm attempting to restrict an API's content type in a RoR application, with a method that gets inherited by all controllers.

```
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/vnd.api+json'

def restrict_content_Type
  return if request.content_type = CONTENT_TYPE

  render_content_type_error
end
```

this works fine, but now I must use a different content type for a single endpoint and controller, and I'd like to just change the content of the `CONTENT_TYPE` constant while reusing the code I already have. To use a different constant I must use a reader method that looks up the constant in the current controller.

I refactored the code into:

```
def get_content_type
  self::CONTENT_TYPE
end

def restrict_content_type
  return if request.content_type == get_content_type
  ...
end
```

The reason I've used a `get_*` reader is that self.content_type returns the `Request`'s content type: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Response.html#method-i-content_type

At this point Rubocop is complaining because of the name I used, `get_*`readers are not idiomatic Ruby.

I can surely override this behaviour in rubocop but I'd like to hear what are my other options and if there are other solutions, because I don't like the name of the method either.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some other names that reveals the purpose of this this method, e.g. `current_content_type`, `restricted_content_type`, `disabled_content_type` - whatever suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

About the naming it could be nice to have a method called `invalid_content_type?` which returns a `Boolean`.

For e.g :

```
def invalid_content_type?(content_type)
  request.content_type == content_type
end

def restrict_content_type
  return if invalid_content_type(self::CONTENT_TYPE)
  ...
end
```